# Error to sum of Euler phi-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The number theory identity $\phi(1) + \phi(2) + \dots + \phi(n) \approx \frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}$ can be interpreted as counting relatively prime pairs of numbers $0 \leq \{ x,y \} \leq n$ .

[image]

Has anyone studied the distribution of error term?  $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k) - \frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}\right]$$ It looks like white noise:

[image]

The histogram has a distinctive shape, maybe hard to prove.  I suspect it's the Gaussian Unitary Ensemble (a Hermite polynomial times a Gaussian).

[image]

---

Similar questions:

[Question concerning the arithmetic average of the Euler phi function:](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13510/question-concerning-the-arithmetic-average-of-the-euler-phi-function)

[averages of Euler-phi function and similar](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84571/averages-of-euler-phi-function-and-similar)

Comment: Sorry to contribute more *noise* to this post, but somehow I feel that this question admits an easy (fourier) answer, but unfortunately, I lack the knowledge to turn my feeling into a concrete answer.

Comment: @Suvrit Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \phi(k) k^{-s} = \frac{\zeta(s-1}{\zeta(s)}$ then $\sum_{k \le n} \phi(k)$ has an explicit formula (which converges in the sense of distributions) in term of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$

Comment: @reuns, this is surprisingly wrong: the main contribution of the error term for this formula does *not* come from the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$. This is explained quite well in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2010.06.010

Answer (score 17):

This is an interesting question. I don't think anyone has worked out what the distribution of the error term
$$\frac{E(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n \leq x}{\phi(n)} - \frac{3x^2}{\pi^2}\right)$$
actually *looks like* in any useful sense; from what I can make out, it seems to essentially be the same as the distribution of
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, but this doesn't really seem to tell you anything particularly useful.

Nevertheless, it certainly is known that $E(x)/x$ has a distribution function; this is proved on p.13 of "[On the Existence of Limiting Distributions of Some Number-Theoretic Error Terms](http://hkumath.hku.hk/~yklau/p/17.pdf)" by Yuk-Kam Lau. This also follows quite easily from the fact that
$$\frac{E(x)}{x} = H(x) + O\left((\log x)^{-4}\right)$$
where
$$H(x) = \sum_{n \leq x}{\frac{\phi(n)}{n}} - \frac{6 x}{\pi^2}$$
combined with the main result of the paper "[The Existence of a Distribution Function for an Error Term Related to the Euler Function](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1955-16.pdf)" by Erdős and Shapiro. What is better known is the average behaviour of $E(x)$, in the form of the asymptotics
$$\sum_{n \leq x}{E(x)} \sim \frac{3 x^2}{2 \pi^2}$$
and
$$\int^{x}_{0}{E(t)^2 dt} \sim \frac{x^3}{6 \pi^2}.$$

Probably the best reference for what is currently known about this error term is the paper "[Oscillations of the remainder term related to the Euler totient function](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X10001873)" by Kaczorowski and Wiertelak (but unfortunately this paper isn't available for free online).

---

EDIT: Very recently, [Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06168) have reproven the existence of the limiting distribution of $E(x)/x$, as well as quantitative bounds for the tails of this distribution; see Theorem 1.3 of their paper.

Comment: I like your first expression with the Mobius function.  Since my plot has three peaks, they may be related to the three values of $\mu(x) = -1,0,1$.