# Mean and median of error term of average Euler-phi function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Lets $\phi(n)$ is Euler's phi function. Let's define error term 
$$
d(n) =  {E(n) \over n} = {1 \over n} \left(\sum_{i\le n}\phi(i)  - {3 n^2 \over \pi^2}\right)
$$

Is it known that asymptotic of mean (and median) of the first N values  $d(n)$ is equal to 3/\pi^2?

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} {\sum_{n=1}^N d(n) \over N} =  3/\pi^2
$$

I can't extract this fact from the papers [Oscillations of the remainder term related to the Euler totient function](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X10001873) and [The Existence of a Distribution Function for an Error Term Related to the Euler Function](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1955-16.pdf).

[Mathematica code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1NKs.jpg)

Update: bug fixed -  the limit is not 1 but  3/π^2, as noticed below by GH from MO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit is not $1$ but $3/\pi^2$ (in agreement with [your Mathematica code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1NKs.jpg)). To see this, let us use the following result of Pillai and Chowla ([On the error terms in some asymptotic formulae in the theory of numbers, (I)](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-5.2.95), J. London Math. Soc. 5 (1930), 95-101):
$$S(x):=\sum_{n\leq x}E(n)=\left(\frac{3}{2\pi^2}+o(1)\right)x^2.$$
We infer
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{E(n)}{n}&=\int_{1-}^N\frac{dS(x)}{x}=\frac{S(N)}{N}+\int_1^N\frac{S(x)}{x^2}\,dx\\[8pt]
&=\left(\frac{3}{2\pi^2}+o(1)\right)N+\int_1^N\left(\frac{3}{2\pi^2}+o(1)\right)dx\\[8pt]
&=\left(\frac{3}{\pi^2}+o(1)\right)N.\end{align*}

Comment: I also pointed out this asymptotic for $S(x)$ in my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95836/error-to-sum-of-euler-phi-functions/95975#95975