# On a result of Montgomery and Vaughan about Euler's totient

Tags: nt.number-theory

The answer to the MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13510/question-concerning-the-arithmetic-average-of-the-euler-phi-function) refers to a result from Montgomery and Vaughan, stating that 
$$\lim\sup \frac{R(x)}{x\sqrt{\log\log(x)}}>0,$$
where $R(x)$ is the approximation error
$$R(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)-\frac{3x^2}{\pi^2}.$$

By Mellin inversion and Cauchy's theorem, this approximation error is related to the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ by
$$R(x)=\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s-1)x^sds}{\zeta(s)s},$$
where $1<\sigma<2$.

I had initially thought it was a typo, that $x$ should be under the root, that the result is conditional and appears to be the law of the iterated logarithm.

> Thus, is it a typo or, if not, why does it not suggest that $\zeta(s)$ has zeros arbitrarily close to $\sigma=1$?

I am assuming it does not suggest that because no corollaries were mentioned.

Comment: I don't know, but I can give you the Montgomery citation: Fluctuations in the mean of Euler's phi function, Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. Math. Sci. 97 (1987), no. 1-3, 239–245 (1988), MR0983617 (90e:11138). 

Comment: Perhaps I am totally confused, but AFAIK, the result is actually Omega plus/minus result and since the summands can be of size x and by continuity a *sublinear* (in x) lower boudn for the error would not really be a result. So the x should not be under the root. I do not oversee the rest of your question at the moment.   

Comment: Sorry the comment before does not quite make sense, I still leave it for the moment. In any case when summing things of size x a sqrt lower bound the size of x would seem strange to me. 

Comment: I don't think the integral you have written down has very proper convergence properties, on the vertical lines. If you smooth the counting function, with a Mellin transform that decays enough as $t\rightarrow\infty$, then I think I agree that the zeros are more closely linked.


Comment: Okay, thank you both. @Quid: Given that $\phi$ can be of size $x$, why would a sublinear lower bound not really be a result?

Comment: @ Junkie: Indeed, but there are $O$ results of trivially larger size (in $x$), so I have implicitly assumed the contour could be taken that far at least. 

Comment: I think what is going on is that the numerator $\zeta(s-1)$ is growing polynomially in $\operatorname{Im}(s)$ in the critical strip, so it is possible for zeroes well inside that strip (and in particular on the critical line) to contribute terms roughly on the order of $x$ to $R(x)$, in contrast with say the error in the prime number theorem.  In any event, since $R(n+1)-R(n) = \phi(n) - 6n/\pi^2 + O(1)$, one cannot hope for universal bounds on $R(x)$ that are significantly better than $O(x)$.

Comment: ... that should read $R(n)-R(n-1)$ instead of $R(n+1)-R(n)$ of course.  In particular, when $p$ is prime we have $R(p)-R(p-1) = (1-6/\pi^2) p + O(1)$ and so this already rules out any universal bound of the form $R(x)=o(x)$.

Comment: Thank you Terry, just to make sure I understand your point, you are speaking of the zeros of the denominator, and thus the polynomial growth of $\zeta(s-1) as $t\rightarrow\infty$, $0<\sigma<1$?

Comment: @Kevin Smith: as I admitted myself it does not quite make sense ;) It would be true had I omitted the "plus/minus" but then as you seem to assert positivity of the error term (as opposed to its absolute value) this would be weaker. The reason why an Omega-result sublinear is $x$ would be 'no result' is given by Terry Tao. To put it slightly differently the function on the left is piece-wise constant and has "jumps" of size about $x$, you can never approximate this by a *continous* function without making an error linear in $x$ somewhere. Sorry again for the slopiness. 

Comment: I think there is no need to talk about the zeros of the denominator. If we assume RH then the integrand is holomorphic in $1/2<\Re s<1$, but $\zeta(s-1)/(s\zeta(s))$ is too large to apply the residue theorem and shift the contour. In fact for $\Re s\approx 1/2$ this fraction barely has any decay in $\Im s$, but we would integrate it over a line segment of length $\approx x$. The result of Montgomery and Vaughan tells us that this effect is already serious for $\Re s$ slightly on the left of $1$. This resonates with Greg Martin's response below.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a typo - I've read the proof before (the proof, by the way, doesn't invoke complex analysis at any point; it's very hands-on).

We're used to using Perron's formula / Mellin transforms to write the summatory function of an arithmetic function (such as $\Lambda(n)$ or $\phi(n)$) as a integral over a vertical contour, then moving that contour to the left and saying that the asymptotic behavior of the summatory function is governed by the residues of the poles we move the contour over. But that can only be rigorously established when the remaining part of the contour can be suitably estimated. I think if you try to apply this method here, you'll find that the integrand simply cannot be estimated nicely enough to make the argument work.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this explanation Greg Martin. So, is this scenario therefore similar to, say, the inverse Mellin transform of $\zeta(s)/-1/(s-1)$, where an $O(1)$ contribution persists regardless of where one integrates? 

Comment: That is, assuming RH, is it the case that the line of integration still cannot be moved to anywhere to the right of that line, even though there would be no poles there? That is, is this a limitation of Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @Kevin: It is not a limitation of Cauchy's theorem, but integrals being large.